# jQuery Droppable - Make an Update Statement after an element gets dropped

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I want to do an update statement in my database, after an element gets dropped on a jQuery UI droppable element.

```
$("#pictures th div").droppable({drop: function(ev, ui) { 
    alert('You filled this box with a picture');
    var this_id = $(ui.draggable).attr("alt");
    var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id"); 
}
```

I know how to get the information (see the code above) I need, but how can I put them now into the database ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is a very open-ended question. You haven't told us what information you want to put into your database, or even what type of database it is (although I assume mySQL given your PHP tag)

Comment: I want to update my Table AlbumPosition with the name of picture, which is in this case "this_id" und the id of object it was dropped in (draggableId). Sry, forgot about the type of the database, but yes it is a mySQL Database.

This update Statement shouldn´t require a reload of the page !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, you can use jQuery's $.post() method to post to a PHP file you've written. In the $.post(), you can pass the ids you would like to have written to your database.

So something like this:

```
$.post("/save.php", { imageId: this_id, draggedId: draggableId }, function (data) {
    alert("success!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Post the variable values to other page lyk this:

```
     $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "data.php",
 data: "Cat=" + id + "&Wid=" + WID
 });
```

and then on data.php page get the values lyk this:

```
 $Cat=$_POST['Cat'];
    $WID=$_POST['Wid'];
```

simply store them in database by using insert query,hope it will help you.